# Ratio of positive to negative data to use when training a cascade classifier (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, training-data, adaboost

So I'm using OpenCV's LBP detector. The shapes I'm detecting are all roughly circular (differing mostly in aspect ratio), with some wide changes in brightness/contrast, and a little bit of occlusion.

OpenCV's guide on how to train the detector is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html)

My main question to anyone with experience using it is how numPos and numNeg should be in relation to eachother? I have roughly 1000 positive samples (so ~900 being used per stage)

What I need to decide is how many negative samples to use per stage for training. I have about 20000 images from which to draw negative data, so redundancy isn't really an issue.

In general the rule I hear is 1:2, but that seems like under-utilization, given how much negative data I have at my disposal. On the flip side, what effects should I expect if I train my detector with 1:20? How should I determine the proper ratio?

Comment: what did you come up with? I'm training my first classifier right now, I too am starting with the LBP, I've collected 260 positive images and 3000 negative images. I'm running the training right now. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend trying a few different configurations and seeing empirically what works best.

In my case, the best option was 1:5. I kept all of my negative data and augmented the positive set with different croppings and rotations